# Finding duplicate values in a table with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-server-2012

I have a data file that has many duplicate values. I want both the original and the duplicate values to be identified and original and duplicate values to be ordered side by side.

My Data files headings are like this along with the data:

[image]

I want the data to be like this:

[image]

I have already found the duplicate values using following query:

```
SELECT a.[wallet] into KYCNew2
  from [dbo].[KYCNew1] A
GROUP BY a.[wallet]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

It has shown only the duplicate values. However I do not have any idea how to make the original and duplicate values and both of their associated data side by side. Would any one help me please?

Comment: Does it have to be in one query?

Comment: How would you identify the duplicate and original values. Any column like create date or flag for active inactive etc.???

Comment: any chance of changing the images to something that can be cut and pasted.

Comment: @amit ranjan: no. Just need the job done

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `row_number()` and `pivot` will do this. You'll need to know the maximum number of duplicates before hand to see everything.

```
Select
  account,
  [1] as path1,
  [2] as path2
From (
  select
    account,
    path,
    row_number() over (partition by account order by path) r
  From
    Dups
  ) x
pivot (
  min(path)
for 
  r in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd9e4/5)</kbd>**